# Predefined User Input with Watson Assistant

Tags: watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying to build a Watson chatbot (Assistant) that will use pre-defined dialog options instead of the free-flowing text input method, such as this: https://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/sh-techcrunch-facebook-messenger.png .

Is there a way to do this, either in "advanced mode" or through the GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are deploying your chatbot to a WordPress site, we actually support this functionality out of the box.

Once you install the [IBM Watson Assistant plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/conversation-watson/) and go to its settings page, you'll find detailed instructions in the Advanced tab.

The process is quite simple.

In the JSON editor for your node response, add an array of predefined `options` on the same level as the `text` key.

[image: Adding options via the JSON editor]

The options will then be displayed as buttons in the chat box, whenever that particular response is issued:

[image: Options displayed by the WordPress pop up]

If you are not using our WordPress plugin, it's trickier because your app will have to implement this last part from scratch. However, the basic idea remains the same.

Your app could retrieve the `options` values from the response and generate the appropriate buttons depending on these values. The WordPress plugin just makes the whole process dead simple.

It's worth noting that this options syntax is a convention we introduced through our WordPress plugin rather than an official specification. It's very likely that the Watson Assistant team will introduce a standard syntax to handle this scenario, in the future.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this specifically through Watson Assistant because you are just building the backend component, not the full application that can use Watson Assistant.

You would have to program the front end that consumes the Watson Assistant API to send the pre-defined dialog options you want to send.

Additionally, you could deploy to Facebook Messenger. It might be able to do this through config on their UI, but I haven't used it. I would recommend editing your question to be specific to Facebook Messenger if you want an answer about the functionality available there.